# Enumerating intersections of two sequences

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary, numbers, bit-manipulation

I have two sequences:

1. Multiples of an unsigned 64-bit number `k`, example for `k=5`: `{0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, ...}`
2. Subsets of the 64-bit mask `m` plus 64-bit constant `C`, example for `m=0b1011`: `{C+0, C+1, C+2, C+3, C+8, C+9, C+10, C+11}`. Note: `C` is disjoint from `m`, aka `(m & C) = 0`.

Aside from checking each and every multiple of `k` and checking if it matches the second sequence criteria, or checking every subset of the mask `m` and ORing with `C` and checking for division with `k`, are there any other ways I can enumerate all the intersection of those two sequences?

A 64-bit number `P` is in the intersection of those two sequences if `P % k == 0` and `(P & C) == C` and `(P & ~(C | m)) = 0`.

Note: Enumerating over the second sequence is actually really easy:

```
uint64_t m = ..., C = ...;
uint64_t subset = 0;
do {
    uint64_t value = subset + C;
    print(value);
    // if (value % 5)   => in the intersection of the sequences
    subset = (subset - m) & m;
} while (subset != 0);
```

Edit: The order of enumeration doesn't matter

Also: I don't exactly hope to enumerate them all, but I want to have some sort of iterator which I can always advance and get the next intersection

Comment: Does the enumeration of the intersection need to be in any particular order?

Comment: @greybeard No, not neccesary

Comment: It might be easier to iterate over all multiples of `k` instead, which also avoids integer division. For each `k * i`, check if it's in the second sequence.

Comment: @JanSchultke I pointed it out in the post however for large `m` and small `k` it is unfeasible

Comment: For `k==2` and `m == ~0`, roughly half of all 64-bit numbers are in the intersection. Just printing them all will take approximately forever, even if it somehow takes just `O(1)` to discover the next member. Are there constraints on `k`, `m` and/or `C` that would make full enumeration reasonable; or some further processing of the result that would make full enumeration unnecessary? What's the ultimate goal of the exercise, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: The loop in "enumerating is really easy" example makes exactly one iteration. Clearly, `(subset - m) & subset == 0` when `subset == 0` (because `anyting & 0 == 0`)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My bad - intention was `(subset - m) & m`. I just want to construct an iterator that allows me to easily discover the next intersection, I have no real hope of iterating over all intersections.

Comment: @DavisHerring My bad - edited. Now it is `(subset - m) & m`.

Comment: Can we assume that `C` is reasonably small relative to the range?

Comment: @btilly `C` would have less bits than `m` for sure, but it may be bigger than `m`

Comment: How big can k be?

Comment: You said an iterator to "get the next iteration" but also that the "order of enumeration doesn't matter." Does that mean we can just have an iterator that advances to an arbitrary unvisited element of the intersection?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes. Both completely arbitary 64-bit integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C mod k` is a constant that means we are looking for subsets of `m` that achieve one and only one value mod `k` — the one that when added to `C mod k` is zero mod `k`.

```
x = (k - (C mod k)) mod k
```

Each of the bits of `m` as a power of 2 is also constant mod `k`. So the task seems to be enumerating those combinations that sum to `x` mod k.

For example, for each of seen combinations, generate a new one by adding the current power of 2 in `m` mod `k`. One immediate optimisation could be to group the powers of 2 in `m` that are equal mod `k`. Other than that, I don't know of a trick to speed that kind of search up -- the number of combination states mod `k` could depend on both `k` and `m`.